# GraphAPI AddAsync() method throws a null reference error when trying to add DirectoryObject to member group

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, nullreferenceexception

XXXFunction is calling a function where the null reference failure is thrown with this line of code below:

```
 await client.Groups[groupId].Members.References.Request().AddAsync(directoryObject);
```

The error is:

```
XXXFunction Failed due to System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at XXXFunctionApp.XXX.Processors.XXXProcessor.<ProcessAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at XXXFunctionApp.XXX.Functions.XXXFunction.<Run>d__3.MoveNext()
```

What is an effective way to handle this null reference? Are there instances where this could be thrown due to the GraphAPI unable to fetch the user due to long running processes, etc.?